# menu.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function

Tags: javascript, error, magento2.3, magento2.3.1, required

I am trying to add a jquery script to my site. I have updated the require-config so it has this-

```
var config = {
paths: {
    slick: 'js/slick.min',
    slaask: 'js/customscript',
    menu: 'js/menu.js'
},
shim: {
    slick: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    menu: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
};
```

The script looks like this-

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Collapsible Menu
    function accordion(trigger) {
        //variables
        var $button = $(trigger);//trigger firing the event
        //visible = true;//flag for wayfinding

        $button.hover().css({'cursor': 'pointer'});

        //event
        $button.click(function () {

            //conditional check
            if ($(this).find('.panel-content').css('display') == 'none') {
                $button.removeClass('active');
                $('.panel-title .icon').html('&oplus;');


                $(this).next().slideUp('slow', function () {
                    $(this).addClass('visuallyhidden').slideDown(0);
                    $('.panel-content').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                });

            } else {
                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $('.panel-title.active .icon').html('&oplus;');
                    $('.panel-title.active').next().slideUp('slow');
                    $('.panel-title.active + .panel-content').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                    $('.panel-title.active').removeClass('active');
                }
                else {
                    $('.panel-title.active .icon').html('&oplus;');
                    $('.panel-title.active').next().slideUp('slow');
                    $('.panel-title.active + .panel-content').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                    $('.panel-title.active').removeClass('active');

                    $button.addClass('active');
                    $('.panel-title.active .icon').html('&otimes;');

                    $(this).next().slideUp(0, function () {
                        $('.panel-content').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
                        $(this).removeClass('visuallyhidden').slideDown('slow');
                    });
                }
            }

            //flag dude

            return false
        });
    }

    //call to widget trigger1
    accordion('#trigger1');
    //call to widget trigger2
    accordion('#trigger2');
    //call to widget trigger3
    accordion('#trigger3');

});//end document.ready()
});
```

The error I am getting is-

Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at menu.js:1

Why am I getting that error?

Comment: Change js/menu.js in paths to js/menu  and redeploy should fix your error

Comment: Also in your require statement set require(['jquery', 'menu'], function($) {

Comment: OK if that didn't work it may be that the menu.js is requiring a file within it which it is unable to use can u post the content of menu.js had similar issue the other day with menu-js library

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = {
paths: {
    slick: 'js/slick.min',
    slaask: 'js/customscript',
    menu: 'js/menu'
},
shim: {
    slick: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    menu: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
};
```

The script looks like this-

```
require(['jquery', 'menu'], function($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Collapsible Menu
    function accordion(trigger) {
        //variables
        var $button = $(trigger);//trigger firing the event
        //visible = true;//flag for wayfinding

        $button.hover().css({'cursor': 'pointer'});

        //event
        $button.click(function () {

            //conditional check
            if ($(this).find('.panel-content').css('display') == 'none') {
                $button.removeClass('active');
                $('.panel-title .icon').html('&oplus;');


                $(this).next().slideUp('slow', function () {
                    $(this).addClass('visuallyhidden').slideDown(0);
                    $('.panel-content').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                });

            } else {
                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $('.panel-title.active .icon').html('&oplus;');
                    $('.panel-title.active').next().slideUp('slow');
                    $('.panel-title.active + .panel-content').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                    $('.panel-title.active').removeClass('active');
                }
                else {
                    $('.panel-title.active .icon').html('&oplus;');
                    $('.panel-title.active').next().slideUp('slow');
                    $('.panel-title.active + .panel-content').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                    $('.panel-title.active').removeClass('active');

                    $button.addClass('active');
                    $('.panel-title.active .icon').html('&otimes;');

                    $(this).next().slideUp(0, function () {
                        $('.panel-content').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
                        $(this).removeClass('visuallyhidden').slideDown('slow');
                    });
                }
            }

            //flag dude

            return false
        });
    }

    //call to widget trigger1
    accordion('#trigger1');
    //call to widget trigger2
    accordion('#trigger2');
    //call to widget trigger3
    accordion('#trigger3');

});//end document.ready()
});
```

Redeploy and should work for you

Comment: Still getting the exact same error. I did a full static content deploy and can see the new code- require(['jquery','menu'], function($)  and I made the change into the require file. I made sure I could see both changes on the front end and I am still getting the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the require-config.js and write down the js as below

```
var config = {
            paths: {
                'slick': 'Vendor_Module/slick.min',
                'slaask': 'Vendor_Module/customscript',
                'menu': 'Vendor_Module/menu.js'
            },
            shim: {
                'slick': {
                    deps: ['jquery']
                },
                'slaask': {
                    deps: ['jquery']
                },
                'menu': {
                    deps: ['jquery']
                }
        }
    };
```

2. and if u want to use this js into your require js than just using below method you can just pass the jQuery dependency into the require js like below in your phtml file

   require(['jquery', 'domReady!', 'slick', 'slaask', 'menu'], function($) {
       "use strict";

   ```
   // javascript here
   ```

   });

Comment: This looks like you added a Slaask change. That is working just fine. Why would I change that?

Comment: you have to add the jquery dependency using the shim in require-config.js and you do not a dependency for slaask js

Comment: But Slaask is working fine. I just need help with the menu.